Theft of deposit
A service provider takes payment from a customer and now the service provider cannot be found. No one answers the phone and they have done this to other people.  Is this theft?

Questions asking for legal advice are off-topic here. I've edited your question to make it generic. You can rollback my edit if you don't like it but there's a good chance the question will be closed if you don't make a similar edit yourself.

There are rules that depend on specific jurisdictions.

This is not theft
It might be fraud if it can be proved that the person who took the money never intended to perform the work being paid for.
However, there are plenty of non-criminal reasons why this could happen. The business might have gone broke, the person might have died, or, even, the person might have decided - after they took the deposit - to just not do the work. All of these are a breach of contract, but none of them is a crime.

The definition of theft differs quite a bit from jurisdiction to jurisdiction. In some jurisdictions, obtaining property by deception is theft.
